# How to get private property in parent class into extended class?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I am not sure if my function is firing before another funciton or if I am having issues with the `$this` variable when I am extending my class.

I am creating a function in my functions.php file.
Here's [a link](http://pastebin.com/Z2FdNufd) to my function.

The specific function is extending a class that is an extension for WooCommerce.
The template page calls the function like so:

```
<?php
    $ssi_woocommerce_variation_control_output = new SSi_WC_Swatch_Picker( $product->id, $attributes, $variation_params['selected_attributes'] );
    print_r($ssi_woocommerce_variation_control_output);
    $ssi_woocommerce_variation_control_output->picker();
?>
```

The `print_r` output will produce the array content to the page. However I get this:

```
Start the Loop

Notice: Undefined property: SSi_WC_Swatch_Picker::$attributes in /my_url/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /my_url/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php on line 13

End the Loop
```

---

UPDATE
Good news (at least for me) the developer of the original class is going to change the `private` properties to `protected` and then I can access them without issue.

Comment: I changed the title to reflect better what was happening.

Comment: I have also decided based off the properties being private to just extend the class and re-use the entire class and adjust the picker() method to suite my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `$attribute` is declared as `private` in the super class, so you can't access it directly from subclasses.

Comment: Yup I looked at the class I'm extending, it has that set to private. So is there nothing I can do then? Would proving the superclass code be beneficial at this point?

Comment: If parent class provides getter methods for these variables you have to use them.

Comment: This is quickly spiraling out of my wheelhouse. How would I find out if there are getter methods? I created a paste of the original class here. http://pastebin.com/EWCn7UCX

Comment: Getter methods are methods that returns an object property. If your parent class has these properties set as private and doesn't provide getter method, maybe the author doesn't want let other to manipulate them and you have to find a workaround to deal with them. You can always modify visibility of that attributes to `protected` ( not `private` ) but this is **dangerous** because others can use that class.

Comment: As a little experiment I changed the attributes `private` to `protected` and they appeared on the page correctly. Now I need to figure out how to achieve this without editing the core plug-in or if it is even possible.